# Order statistics on the spacings between order statistics for the uniform distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

For any natural $n$, let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be independent identically distributed 
random variables each uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$.  As usual, let $U_{n:1}\le\cdots\le U_{n:n}$ denote the corresponding order statistics. Consider
\begin{equation}\label{eq:G_i}
 G_i:=U_{n:i}-U_{n:i-1} \quad \text{for}\quad i=1,\dots,n+1, 
\end{equation}
where $U_{n:0}:=0$ and $U_{n+1:n+1}:=1$.

One may refer to the $G_i$'s as the gaps or, as it is usually done in the literature, the spacings between the consecutive order statistics. 
Let now 
$$
 G_{n+1:1}\le\cdots\le G_{n+1:n+1}
$$ 
denote the ordered gaps $G_1,\dots,G_{n+1}$, so that the random sets $\{G_{n+1:1},\dots, G_{n+1:n+1}\}$ and $\{G_1,\dots,G_{n+1}\}$ are the same.

[Fisher](https://www.jstor.org/stable/95247) obtained the distribution of the largest gap, $G_{n+1:n+1}$. Fisher's result was generalized in [this note](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06406), where the distribution of the $k$th smallest gap, $G_{n+1:k}$, was obtained, for each $k=1,\dots,n+1$.

Does anyone know other references to these or other related results in the literature?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out that this result is due to [Irwin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2342709?seq=1).

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2983737.pdf  too?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : Thank you for your comment. Yes, that paper by Barton and David is where I found the reference to Irwin.

Comment: Note also that exercise 667 in Whitworth's DDC Exercises precedes Fisher by roughly 30 years.